# Set a json object property to HTML

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying something like

```
var template = new Object();
template.DescriptionHTML ='*html content goes in here*'
```

This is why:

When the user clicks on a button a popup window opens where he/she can enter html text using a WYSIWYG editor. When they click submit, I want to pass the HTML content to the parent page using jQuery. Now this works if I am passing plain text from pop up to parent. But if I try to pass HTML it breaks. I don't want to escape the HTML characters because in the parent page I want to display the HTML content. How can this be done?

I am aware of alternatives such as posting back the parent page and getting the updated content. But I would appreciate if the responses can be limited to making the above scenario work.

Comment: Note: JSON is a string not an object ... you can parse a JSON string to a JavaScript object ....

Answer (score 1):

this works, the important bit is to only have jquery referenced from the main window not the popup and control the popup from there

Main Window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Window</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".editable").click(function () {
                var 
                    $element = $(this),
                    popupWindow = window.open("popup.html", "popup", "width=525,height=250");

                $(popupWindow).load(function () {
                    var 
                        $editor = $(popupWindow.document).find("#Editor"),
                        $submit = $(popupWindow.document).find("#Submit");

                    $editor.val($element.html());
                    $submit.click(function () {
                        $element.html($editor.val());
                        popupWindow.close();
                    });
                });

                popupWindow.element = this;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="editable">
        <p>I'm editable click me</p>
    </div>

    <div class="editable">
        <p>I'm editable as well click me</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Popup window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Popup Window</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="Editor" rows=10 cols=60></textarea>
    <input id="Submit" value="Submit" type="button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$('#submitbuttonid').click(function() { or $('#formid').submit(function() {
   var html = $('#textarea').html();
   // do what you want with it from here
   template = [];
   template.DescriptionHTML = html;
});
```

you need to change `submitbuttonid` to the `id` of the submit button or `formid` to the `id` of the form submitted and `#textarea` to the WYSIWYG textarea `id`.

This uses [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Fetching the HTML is not an issue. the problem is that, since the html has special characters, it breaks the code :(.

Comment: @developer747 Try [encoding the HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should use an absolutely positioned div (dialog) rather than a popup window?
that way your not getting into separate window issues such as permissions an popup blockers

then ManseUK's code above would work for you

Comment: I have to add a pop up to be consistent with the rest of the web application :(